# Output key with the value

Tags: json, bash, jq

Given a json object (stored as bash variable $test)

```
{
  "foo": {
    "name": "my foo"
  },
  "bar": {
    "name": "my bar"
  }
}
```

If I want to output

```
{
  "foo": {
    "name": "my foo"
  }
}
```

It looks like I have to use

```
$ jq '. | with_entries(select(.key == "foo"))' <<<$test
{
  "foo": {
    "name": "my foo"
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler method to achieve same outcome?

Comment: You really should have double quotes arounld the variable interpolation `<<<"$test"`

Comment: The quotes aren't strictly necessary in recent versions of `bash`; prior to version 4.4 various bugs existed that required the quotes as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

```
jq '{foo}'
```

### Explanation

`{foo}` is an abbreviation for `{"foo": .foo}`

:-)

### Caveat

The abbreviated form can only be used for key names that are not jq [keywords](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/How-to:-Avoid-Pitfalls#keywords) (such as `if`).  However:

```
$ jq -n '{"if"}'
{
  "if": null
}
```